# send location on bot framework to facebook messenger

Tags: botframework

How can I send a location ( that opens like a map ) from the bot to facebook messenger? I want it to appear like a map as if the user is sending his location

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for this, but it's pretty easy to generate a map image using the Bing Maps API (see docs on [how to create a static map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx)).  You could embed this in a HeroCard with a tap action that takes the user to a live version of the map.

Comment: But in this way , it would be an image right ?  not a map object I guess

Comment: Correct, but you can make the image link to a live version of the map.

Comment: To sum up to Lars's answer, I believe what he explained is now available at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-location